# Using sed to delete all vowels

Tags: unix, sed

How do I delete every vowel from a file?

AEIOU Example: `Hi Im Brad` --> `H m Brd`

I know deleting one character is like sed `'s/a//'` right? `'s/a/e/i/o/u/'` doesn't work.

Answer (score 8):

What you want to do is specify a group of letters that you want to remove. This is done using `[]`.

```
sed 's/[aeiouAEIOU]//g'
```

So for example

```
echo "Hi Im Brad" | sed 's/[aeiouAEIOU]//g'
```

Gives me

```
H m Brd
```

Comment: Thanks man, didn't know you need those brackets, what exactly does the g at the end do here?

Comment: The `g` makes it global, which will search the pattern for multiple occurrences in a line, instead of only the first. If you didn't have it, `stain` would only become `stin`, when you probably were looking for `stn`.

Comment: Take a look here for more in-depth explanations about sed: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html

Answer (score 3):

For single character deletions, you can use the `tr` utility:

```
tr -d '[aeiouAEIOU]'
```

Comment: Thanks man, I know there's easier ways to do it but this is a homework question and for an intro to sed but my teacher didn't explain it very well.

Answer (score 0):

`sed 's/[aeiouAEIOU]*//g' <your file>`

For more information on sed see: http://www.pement.org/sed/sed1line.txt

Comment: * is not really needed in this case ;-)